# Is there any way to hide media controls while video is playing in the WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView inside the activity, I had some URL parsing problems with VideoPlayer (cause my damn country is blocking the URL), so I'm using WebView and if user will click on the video thumb, WebView will open and video will start automatically.

Now the problem is if someone clicks on play button, while video is playing automatically, the buffering progress circle will keep rotating even when video is playing.

So that, I want to hide those media controls while video is playing so user won't be able to click on play button.

Any idea to hide those controls on WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the webview you dont have any permmission to control the any function of video view. you can't controll any function of the site which is open in your webview